# TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, pil

Пытаюсь вытащить с фотографии обводку контуров объектов, но получаю ошибку:

> ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 245,255,0)
>
> TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'

Пробовал cv2.UMat но он не помог, в чем проблема?

```
if not img:
    async with plugin.session.get(photo) as response:
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(await response.read())).convert('L')

if not img:
    return await env.reply('К сожалению, ваше фото исчезло!')

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 245,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

tam = 0

for contorno in contours:
    if len(contorno) > tam:
        contornoGrande = contorno
        tam = len(contorno)

cv2.drawContours(img,contornoGrande.astype('int'),-1,(0,255,0),2)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UMat говорит о том, что задействовано Transparent API/OpenCL.

Это получилось без Вашего ведома?

Если нет, то просто приводите тип

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cv2.UMat(img)...
```

или копируйте img в UMat

```
UMat um; 
im.copyTo(um);
```

Comment: Теперь получаю ошибку- "    ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(cv2.UMat(img), 245,255,0)
TypeError: Required argument 'ranges' (pos 2) not found"

Comment: Это, наверное, преобразование в Umat хочет второй аргумент  - вот [этот конструктор](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d45/classcv_1_1UMat.html#a96f381979b76ce63d497e812fd7ec574), может быть -  что то с типом элемента не то.